# Can't get ApplicationCookie to expire when using Identity and Google Auth in MVC .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, oauth, asp.net-core, google-authentication

So I'm trying to use Identity in conjunction with Google Authentication - which works, except for the fact `ApplicationCookie.ExpireTimeSpan` does not do anything.

**Identity Options**

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options => {

    options.Cookies.ApplicationCookieAuthenticationScheme = "CustCookie";
    options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.AuthenticationScheme = IdentityCookieOptions.ApplicationCookieAuthenticationType = "CustCookie";
    options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.CookieName = "CustCookie";
    options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.AutomaticChallenge = true;
    options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
    options.Cookies.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme = "Google";
    options.Cookies.ExternalCookie.AuthenticationScheme = IdentityCookieOptions.ApplicationCookieAuthenticationType = "Google";

    // Does not work.
    options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(2);
})
```

**Using Identity**

```
app.UseIdentity()
    .UseGoogleAuthentication(options => {
        options.ClientId     = xx;
        options.ClientSecret = xx;
        options.SignInScheme = "CustCookie";
        options.AuthenticationScheme = "Google";

        options.Events = new OAuthEvents {
           OnCreatingTicket = context =>
           {
               //....Get Claims -snip-
           }
        }
});
```

Does it have to do with me messing up declaring my `ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme`(I found no documentation or examples online for ExternalCookies)?

**If I use the default authentication schemes, the expiration works, but the claims I obtain in `OnCreatingTicket` don't get set.**

Can anyone lend a hand?

Comment: Holy Hell, I thought I was the only one experiencing this issue.